# Django formtools SessionWizardView repopulating form on validation error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formtools

I've a `django-formtools SessionWizardView` wizard which works fine when all data is input.  However, I have form validation going on within each step of the form and if a step is represented I cannot get the entered data to redisplay in some instances.

Here is a simple example.  Required field `description` isn't entered byt field `plan` was entered.  The validation error is reported and the form redisplayed.

I'm creating the plan checkboxes in the template as below.

```
{% for plan in PLANS %}
    <div class="col-6">
         <span class="form-radio form-radio-xl">
             <input type="radio" id="id_job-plan_{{plan.id}}" name="job-plan" value="{{ plan.pk }}" required {% if wizard.form.plan.value == plan.pk %}checked{% endif %}>
              <label for="id_job-plan_{{plan.id}}">{{ plan }} - {{plan.pk}} </label>
         </span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I expect `{% if wizard.form.plan.value == plan.pk %}checked{% endif %}` to be `True` in one instance and therefore `checked`.  It isn't and I do not understand why not.

If I do `{{ wizard.form.plan.value }}` the displayed result **looks** the same as `{{ plan.pk }}`

Comment: Found the answer.  It **looks** the same but `{{ wizard.form.plan.value }}` is a string.  By using `{{ wizard.form.plan.value|add:"0" }}` I coerce it into an integer and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It looks the same but `{{ wizard.form.plan.value }}` is a string. By using `{{ wizard.form.plan.value|add:"0" }}` I coerce it into an integer and now it works